# Copyright of Apps

Tags: android, iphone

I want to know whether word games on the iPhone are copyright protected. For example games like 7 Little Words are on both Android and Iphone. Are they copyright protected.

Can I make an app similar to 7 Little Words and release it to the market?

Comment: You could ask this on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could always create something original, rather than riding the coattails of others. In that case, this is not an issue at all. Don't just be one of the hundreds of copycats on the App Store, challenge yourself and come up with the next great application.

Answer (score 4):

According to USPTO, the rules of a game can not be copyrighted. The characters/artwork printed material (for example a printed list of rules) in a game are subject to copyright.

It's legal to make an identical game with identical rules as long as you don't copy any part of the design and creative components. This is how "Words with Friends" became so popular by copying the game rules of Scrabble, and Hasbro (who owns Scrabble) was not able to take legal action.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any graphics or using modified screen graphics. If your idea is same but your end product implementation is different then the games you are referring ... As far as I know there won't be any issues in releasing your game in Android Market.

Comment: My graphics will be different My interface will be a little different from the original game and will also have interfaces with a different color etc.

Comment: hmm Then I guess there won't be any issues if there's noting copyrighted content included in your app.  As me232 suggested there are no patents held on the game idea in the country you are selling the game.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just to clarify I am not a lawyer. Generally speaking game clones are allowed as long as the game varies enough from the original and there are no patents held on the game idea in the country you are selling the game.

For a brief history see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_clone

I am sure many answers will offer advice of how to avoid being too similar, and ensure you do not emulate the "look and feel" of the game.